# chown from query bind msg

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

how can set from qry .chanset ?

```
bind msg - .flag msg:flag

proc msg:flag {nick uhost handle text} {
    if {$text == ""} {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $nick :.flag #channel on/off"
        return 0
    }

    set chan [lindex [split $text] 0]
    set button [lindex [split $text] 1]
    set flag [lindex [split $text] 2]
    if { [string match -nocase "on" "$button"] } {
        chanset $chan +$flag
    }
    if { [string match -nocase "off" "$button"] } {
        chanset $chan -$flag
    }

    putserv "PRIVMSG $nick :Change Flag Successful."
}
```

error msg on partyline :

```
[18:12:50] Tcl error: invalid command name "chanset"
```

Comment: `chanset` is not a Tcl command.  Are you using some other package that provides `chanset`?

Comment: i set this normal on partyline from eggdrop :(, rehash and restart working perfekt